# Cannot pass function of type '([CLPlacemark]?, (any Error)?) async throws -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have written this code:

In the first step, I read an Excel file that contains the addresses of the buildings as a string.

| LABE | HAUS | Gemeindename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hasenwinkel | 14 | Braunschweig |

The Excel file is similar to the table above.

I want to read the addresses inside a loop and get the coordinates of the addresses (Lat, Long) using CLGeocoder. Using the snapshotImage function, I give the coordinates as input to the function, and if there is picture, I want to save that picture of the target address with its address name.

But I get the following errors:

1.Cannot pass function of type '([CLPlacemark]?, (any Error)?) async throws -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

2. Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '([CLPlacemark]?, (any Error)?) async throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '([CLPlacemark]?, (any Error)?) -> Void'

```
let columnTypes: [String: CSVType] = ["LABE": .string,
                                      "HAUS": .string,
                                      "Gemeindename": .string]


let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Adresse", withExtension: "csv")!
let options = CSVReadingOptions(
    hasHeaderRow: true,
    ignoresEmptyLines: true,
    delimiter: ";"
    )



let result = try DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: path,rows: 0..<50, types: columnTypes,options: options)


enum LookaroundError: Error {
    case unableToCreateScene
}

func snapshotImage(for coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) async throws -> UIImage {
    guard let scene = try await MKLookAroundSceneRequest(coordinate: coordinate).scene else {
        throw LookaroundError.unableToCreateScene
    }
    let options = MKLookAroundSnapshotter.Options()
    options.size = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 500)
    return try await MKLookAroundSnapshotter(scene: scene, options: options).snapshot.image
}

var address: String = ""


for row in result.rows {
    if row["HAUS"] == nil {
        
        address = "\(row["LABE"] ?? <#default value#>) \(row["Gemeindename"] ?? <#default value#>)"
        
    } else {

        address = "\(row["LABE"] ?? <#default value#>) \(row["HAUS"] ?? <#default value#>) \(row["Gemeindename"] ?? <#default value#>)"
    }
    
    print(address)
    
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address){ (placemarks, error) in
        guard
            let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate
        else{
            return
        }
        
        var image = try await snapshotImage(for: location)
        var url = try FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appending(component: "\(address).png")
        try image.pngData()?.write(to: url)
    }
    
}
```

Ideally, I want to read the addresses in this loop and save a picture of them using their coordinates.I don't have much experience in Swift programming. Does anyone have an idea how to solve the code problem?

Comment: Which line exactly? Also `<#default value#>` doesn't cause you issue at all?

Comment: @Larme in for loop in geocoder.geocodeAddressString ... i don’t  think so. that was Xcode suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you exactly what's wrong, but it may not be obvious why it is wrong.

This line

```
var image = try await snapshotImage(for: location)
```

makes the closure you pass to `geocoder.geocodeAddressString` asynchronous. That function will not accept `async` closures. It's not declared to. It's the same as if you passed a throwing closure to a non throwing parameter.

Since you don't provide the definition for `geocoder.geocodeAddressString` it is difficult to suggest a fix. Perhaps just build an array of locations in the loop and then get the snapshot images afterwards.

Comment: I would suggest you make the geocoder `Async` by using a checked continuation. Then you can move the code that is inside the closure out

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you please give me more guidance or edit my code? I am not very professional in programming with Swift

Comment: @JeremyP I wanted to do this at first and I made an empty Array and tried to append the coordinates but i got error. can U write for me a piece  of code for appending a data in an array ?

Comment: @PooriyaRezaei `var myArray: [Whatever] = [] ; myArray.append(someWhatever)` Make sure the array is mutable i.e. don't use `let`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address){ (placemarks, error) in
        guard
            let placemarks = placemarks,
            let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemarks.first?.location?.coordinate
        else{
            return
        }
```

to

```
guard let location = try await geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address).first?.location?.coordinate else { return }
```

or, more correct, mark your function signature with `throws` and

```
do {
    let location = try await geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address).first?.location?.coordinate
} catch {
    throw(error)
}
```

Comment: I made these changes the errors are disappeared , but when I run the program, the Xcode closes suddenly. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I don't see how this is related.

Comment: Is it possible for you to run this code once if U have time?

Comment: As I just told you, this is another issue which is unrelated to this question. I gave you a solution to fix your issue, and it works properly.